# This server supports version 611 and earlier. a downgrade path is not supported

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

Which SQL Server 2005 Express (means in which service packs) to be install to remove like

> this server supports version 611 and earlier. a downgrade path is not supported

Comment: Can you provide more information, it's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: If you read your question back to yourself, does it make any sense to you? As I have no clue what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

None. Your server supports Db version 611, which mean *it is SQL Server 2005*. You are trying to restore or attach a newer version DB (we don't know which, because you choose to cut the message, eliminating what was critical information).

You need to install a SQL Server of a version appropriate for the database you try to restore or attach:

- 612: SQL Server 2005 SP2.
- 655: SQL Server 2008
- 661: SQL Server 2008 R2
- 706: SQL Server 2012