# the database cannot be opened because it is version 655

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I have developed a VB.net application (Visual Studio 2010 - WIN 7) which contains a local database.i have created the setup of my application if I run and I install my app on another PC under WIN XP, the installation of the app is well done but the execution of the application displays a message and the app will not open !! The message:
The database 'Databasename' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 611 and earlier. A upgrade path to an earlier version  is not supported. Could not open new database 'Databasename'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This server supports version 611 and earlier. a downgrade path is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733777/this-server-supports-version-611-and-earlier-a-downgrade-path-is-not-supported)

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778090/exception-database1-mdf-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-655-this-server

Answer (score 0):

Database version 655 is SQL Server 2008, and 611 is SQL Server 2005.

[How to determine version of Local Sql Instance and your database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/02/20/mapping-sql-mdf-file-versions-to-sql-product-versions.aspx)

You will need to upgrade SQL on the XP machine to SQL Server 2008, or downgrade yours to SQL Server 2005.

Alternatively, you can create a new database on the XP machine and then seed it with any needed data for the application to function.